# Extract all the text and img tags from HTML in PHP.

Tags: php, html, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

For a project I need to take a HTML page and extract all its text and img tags from it, and keep them in the same order they appear in the web page.

So for example, if the web page is:

```
<p>Hi</p>
<a href ="test.com" alt="a link"> text link</a>
<img src="test.png" />
<a href ="test.com"><img src="test2.png" /></a>
```

I would like to retrieve that information with this format:

```
text - Hi
Link1 - <a href ="test.com">text link</a>  notice without alt or other tag
Img1 - test.png  
Link2 - <a href ="test.com"><img src="test2.png" /></a>  again no tag
```

Is there a way to make that in PHP?

Comment: What have you tried so far? To get you started, look at using an HTML parser for PHP.

Comment: Have a look at the related links, or even the search.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php

Comment: I wouldn't call it an exact duplicate, the questions cover the same grounds, but they don't ask exactly the same.

Comment: Ok maybe i have forgot to ask a exemple of code because i have search this site and google for the last month i have see alot of code geting one tage but i have never see a example showing what i am looking for that why i ask expert coder just to show a litle example of how doing this. The near i got if with simplehtmlparser but i got dupplicate img,text ... I am not asking link for parser i already consult 99% of them without lock thanks guys

Comment: Well, asking for the codez is even more disliked here. It doesn't seem like you invested a lot of effort as you proclaim. Your question does not show what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make that in php ?

Yes, you can first strip all tags you're not interested in and then use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) to remove all unwanted attributes. Finally you need to re-run [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) to remove tags added by `DomDocument`:

```
$allowed_tags = '<a><img>';
$allowed_attributes = array('href', 'src');

$html = strip_tags($html, $allowed_tags);
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node)
{
    foreach($node->attributes as $attribute)
    {
        if (in_array($attribute->name, $allowed_attributes)) continue;
        $node->removeAttributeNode($attribute);
    }
}

$html = $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagname('body')->item(0));
$html = strip_tags($html, $allowed_tags);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1Ro4z1)

Answer (score -1):

I would use an **[HTML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)** to pull the information out of the website. Get reading.