# Specify iframe Link using Regex

Tags: php, regex, web-applications

***Problem:***

**I need to confirm that iframe have one type of link with the following format:**

```
http://www.example.com/embed/*****11 CHARACTERS MAX.****?rel=0

Starts with: http://www.example.com/embed/
Ends with: ?rel=0
11 CHARACTERS MAX. means in this spot, there can any 11 characters. Don't go beyond 11.
```

NOTE: none of the specified tags are ensured to be in every post. It depends on how user uses the editor.

I'm using PHP

---

I used the line below to make sure all tags are excluded except the ones specified:

```
$rtxt_offer = preg_replace('#<(?!/?(u|br|iframe)\b)[^>]+>#', '', $rtxt_offer);
```

Comment: Please see: [Extract all the text and img tags from HTML in PHP.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8021543/367456) (closed).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php) - Main point: Consider to not use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: Your first regex was basically a reimplementation of `strip_tags()`. You can of course augment it with another assertion just for `|iframe (?=src=)`, but it's not worth the effort. HTMLPurifier might be what you are searching for (though even more effort to do what you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote you only want to validate the link value with a regular expression:

```
$doesMatch = preg_match('~^http://www.example.com/embed/[^?]{0,11}\?rel=0$~', $link);
```

This does specifically what you're asking for.

For removing tags please see `strip_tags` or use a HTML parser to do it, which will also help you to get the link value more properly.

In a similar question/answer I posted some example code how to use `strip_tags` and `SimpleXMLElement` together: [Extract all the text and img tags from HTML in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8021543/367456#8021831).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is built-in function in PHP that strips tags for you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php no need to use slow regex here.

Steps you'll need to solve your problem:

1. Parse this text as [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)
2. Get `iframe` node from it
3. Get src attribute from iframe and parse it with [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
4. Now you can perform easy checks on all components returned by `parse_url`

Happy coding